# $\lim_{x\to a} \tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{2} \right)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I am trying to compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to a} \tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{2} \right)$$

And I must use the fundamental limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ somewhere. I tried a lot of [trigonometrical substitutions](https://www2.clarku.edu/faculty/djoyce/trig/identities.html) but nothing works. Can you give me a hint?

I guess that the solution must be very elementary because in the book I took this limit from, L'Hopital and other tools to compute limits where not introduced yet although I don't know if this is "meaningful", I took this from a problem book and self imposed the rule of using only what was given before it.

Comment: The transformation $t:=x-a$ could help.

Comment: remember that $\tan(y) = \frac{\sin (y)}{\cos (y)}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as suggested in [Joshua's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686026/lim-x-to-a-tan-left-frac-pi-x2a-right-sin-left-fracx-a2-right/4686042#comment9911402_4686026), make a substitution of $y = x - a$ so $x \to a$ becomes $y \to 0$, with your limit then becoming

$$L = \lim_{y\to 0}\tan\left(\frac{\pi(y+a)}{2a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) = \lim_{y\to 0}\tan\left(\frac{y\pi}{2a}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)$$

Next, from the list of [shifts and periodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Shifts_and_periodicity), there's $\tan\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = -\cot(\theta)$, so with $\cot(\theta) = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$, we then get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
L & = \lim_{y\to 0}\left(-\frac{\cos\left(\frac{y\pi}{2a}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{y\pi}{2a}\right)}\right)\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \\
& = \lim_{y\to 0}\left(-\cos\left(\frac{y\pi}{2a}\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{y\pi}{2a}\right)}\right)\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \\
& = \lim_{y\to 0}\left(-\cos\left(\frac{y\pi}{2a}\right)\right)\left(\frac{\frac{y\pi}{2a}}{\sin\left(\frac{y\pi}{2a}\right)}\right)\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}{\frac{y}{2}}\right)\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

I assume you can now finish this.